# Filtrar con char un archivo .txt en C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crud, txt

estoy desarrollando una actividad sobre una aplicación de tareas con archivos de texto en C++.

***Explicación:**
El programa funciona con un archivo .txt al que accede y tiene esta estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El id de línea, el nombre de la tarea, la fecha tope, nombre de la persona y el Nivel de Urgencia (A mayor).

El problema que tengo es que en el método introduces lo que te pide y haga lo que haga no muestra nada, he probado bastantes formas por si el if no estaba bien hecho, pero no se muy bien en que fallo, no se que hacer ya que en otro archivo filtro con un char = '0' y si que busca correctamente las líneas, pero aquí no.

He desarrollado uno que te pide que introduzcas Bajo, Medio o Alto y lo debería filtrar según, A, B o C en el archivo de texto.

Admito cualquier tipo de solución ya que se perfectamente que esto no será la forma más óptima de filtrar ni comparar datos !

***Salida:**
Como Salida debería mostrar las líneas del archivo .txt que coincidan con el nivel de urgencia introducido por el usuario.

Un saludo y muchas gracias !

****Código*****:

```
// **METODO VER TAREA MAS URGENTE**
void Tareas::tareaMasUrgente(){
    ifstream archivo;
    string texto;
    string valorIntroducido = "Defecto";
    archivo.open("tareasList.txt", ios::in);

    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo." << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "\n" << "Introduzca el nivel de Urgencia para FILTRAR: ALTO, MEDIO o BAJO" << "\n\n";
    getline (cin, valorIntroducido);
    cin.ignore ( 100 , '\n');

    if (valorIntroducido == "Alto" || valorIntroducido == "ALTO" || valorIntroducido == "alto")
    {
        nivelUrgencia = 'A';
    } else if (valorIntroducido == "Medio" || valorIntroducido == "MEDIO" || valorIntroducido == "medio")
    {
        nivelUrgencia = 'B';
    } else if (valorIntroducido == "Bajo" || valorIntroducido == "BAJO" || valorIntroducido == "bajo")
    {
        nivelUrgencia = 'C';
    } else {
        nivelUrgencia = 'A'; // Por defecto si no se reconoce nada, buscamos la mas urgente.
    };
    
    while(!archivo.eof()){
        getline(archivo,texto);
        
        replace(texto.begin(), texto.end(), ';', ' ');
        for(int i = 0; i<texto.length(); i++){
            if(texto[i] == nivelUrgencia){
                cout << texto << endl;
            }
        }
   
    }
    archivo.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando C++11 puedes usar el método 'back' de la clase string para acceder a último carácter de la línea.

```
char urgencia = texto.back()
```

y en vez de usar un bucle harías simplemente esto:

```
if(urgencia == nivelUrgencia) cout << texto << endl;
```

Si por alguna razón el metodo anterior no estuviera disponible podrias usar iteradores en este caso un reverse_iterator

```
char urgencia = *texto.rbegin();
```

Si no has aprendido punteros o el uso de iteradores puedes optar por una manera mas trivial accediendo al último carácter de la cadena usando el método 'at'.El último carácter corresponde a la posición "tamaño de la cadena - 1" puesto que se empieza a contar desde 0. Entonces quedaría del siguiente modo

```
char urgencia = texto.at(texto.size() - 1);
```

Luego habría que hacer la comprobación como en el primer ejemplo pero de este modo funciona y te quitas de encima hacer un bucle buscando el último carácter. Espero que te sirva